# how to fetch webform records from table by using drupal db_select

Tags: webforms

i want to display the output in the following format by using the following source code but the following source code shows error

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in eval() (line 20 of /....----modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

[image]

```
<?php
include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'webform').'/includes/webform.submissions.inc');
$query = db_select('webform_submitted_data', 'u');
$query->fields('u', array('sid','nid','data'));
$query->condition('nid','1','=');
$results =$query->execute();

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>  Profile Photo </th>";
echo "<th> Faculty  Name and Department  </th>";
echo  "</tr>";

if($record = $results->fetchAssoc())
{
$sid = $record['sid'];
$nid = $record['nid'];
$submission = webform_get_submission($nid,$sid);
echo "<tr>";
$val = $submission->data[15][0];

$query1 = db_select('file_managed', 'u');
$query1->fields('u', array('fid','filename'));
$query1->condition('fid',$val,'=');
$results1 =$query1->execute();

if ($record1 = $results1->fetchAssoc())
{
$path = $record1['filename'];


echo "<td> <a href ='http://../content/detailed-information/?val=$sid'  target='_blank'><img src ='../profile/$path'   width = '100' height='100' /> </a> </td>";
}
echo "<td><b>" .  "Name : " . $submission->data[1][0] . "</b><br>" .  " Designation : " . $submission->data[2][0] . "<br>" . " Department : " . $submission->data[3][0] ."<br>" . " E-mail : " . $submission->data[4][0] .  "</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as it says, the error is in the line

```
$val = $submission->data[15][0];
```

so the variable `$submission->data[15]` does not contain a value [0]. Most likely the array is empty.

Of course, it's probably a bad idea to go to the database yourself, rather than using [Webforms API functions](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/sites!all!modules!webform!webform.module/). A little [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571256/how-to-get-drupal-webform-module-submited-value-programmticaly) can get you started.

Comment: You've no idea how much time you saved me inadvertently. Thanks man!

Comment: The site linked at the bottom of this answer is no longer active: https://drupalize.me/api-site